# In my SQL query, how can I have a column with values queried from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

This is the query I came up with to get a list of teams that a user is part of:

```
select user_teams.team_id, teams.team_name from
(
    select distinct(team_id) from workflows where workflow_id in (
        select workflow_id from user_workflows where user_name in
        (
            'johndoe'
        )
    )
) user_teams join tbl_teams teams on user_teams.team_id = teams.team_id;
```

The result looks like:

```
team_id    team_name
1          Team A
5          Team E
```

How can I add another column with its value being the number of workflows from that team that the user is assigned?
(I can find this from the workflows and user_workflows table)

It should look like:

```
user_name    team_id    team_name    workflow_count
johndoe       1          Team A       127
johndoe       5          Team E       96
```

I came up with this query but I can't figure out how to have it's result be added to a new column based on the **team_id** and **user_name** from the previous query:

```
select count(distinct(workflow_id, user_name)) from user_workflows
where user_name = 'johndoe'
and workflow_id in
(
    select workflow_id from workflows where team_id in
    (
        select team_id from tbl_teams where team_name in ('Team A')
    )
)
```

Any tips on how I can achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Adding table definitions:

```
tbl_teams(team_id bigserial, team_name text)

workflows(workflow_id bigserial, team_id int8 references(tbl_teams(team_id)), workflow_name)

user_workflows(user_workflow_id bigserial, workflow_id int8 references(workflows(workflow_id)), user_name text)
```

Adding sample data:

```
tbl_teams:
team_id    team_name
1          Team A
2          Team B
3          Team C
4          Team D
5          Team E

workflows:
workflow_id    team_id    workflow_name
1              1          Audit
2              1          Refund
3              3          Purchase
4              4          Discontinue
5              3          Payment

user_workflows:
user_workflow_id    workflow_id    user_name
1                   1              johndoe
2                   1              janedoe
3                   1              alex
4                   3              ron
5                   5              stacey
6                   2              johndoe
7                   2              janedoe
8                   5              ron
9                   5              johndoe
```

Ideal query result:

```
user_name    team_id    team_name    workflow_count
johndoe      1          Audit        2
johndoe      3          Payment      1
alex         1          Audit        1
ron          3          Purchase     2
```

Comment: Table definitions would be of great help in helping you.

Comment: Try this: `with j as (
  select user_teams.team_id, teams.team_name from
  (
    select distinct(team_id) 
    from workflows 
    where workflow_id in (
        select workflow_id from user_workflows where user_name in
        ('johndoe')
   )
) user_teams join tbl_teams teams on user_teams.team_id = teams.team_id)
select j.team_id, j.team_name, user_name, count(*)
from j,user_workflows w 
where j.team_id = w.team_id
group by j.team_id, j.team_name, w.user_name`. Consider adding create table statements and sample data (insert statements) to your question..

Comment: @VBoka I'm not sure it is what the OP needs, and to avoid posting a wrong answer and possibly making other people lose interest in answering the question I prefer to have a feedback from the OP first.

Comment: The OP described what he needs. If you do not understand then ask what you do not understand like Bjarni did. Also, accepted answer cant stop some people from involving and an answer also should not. For example we now have an answer... :)

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson Added table definitions

Comment: @JimJones I've added some sample data for the tables and what the ideal query result would be as well

Comment: @Vinayak in your "Ideal query result:" you mean "workflow_name" not "team_name" ?

Comment: @VBoka Yes, that's correct. It's workflow_name and not team_name. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this goes close to what you need:

```
select uw.user_name
       , tt.team_id
       , tt.team_name
       , count(*) workflow_count
from tbl_teams tt
left join workflows w on tt.team_id = w.team_id
left join user_workflows uw on uw.workflow_id = w.workflow_id
where uw.user_name = 'johndoe'
--and tt.team_name = 'Team A'
group by uw.user_name, tt.team_id, tt.team_name
```

If you will need to filter it by team also then you can remove the commented line.

Here is the comment of the OP as additional info:

> To add to the answer, there were a couple of duplicate entries in the
>   user_workflows table so to get the correct count, I changed

`count(*) workflow_count`

to

`count(distinct(uw.workflow_id, uw.user_name))`

Comment: Unfortunately, user_name is not part of **tbl_teams**. I know that's very weird but I didn't design the schema. The **user_workflows** table has the **user_name**

Comment: Ok, I have changed and with new data I will try to test if it is not ok now ?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. It works perfectly! Thanks @VBoka :)

Comment: Great, happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: To add to the answer, there were a couple of duplicate entries in the user_workflows table so to get the correct count, I changed `count(*) workflow_count` to `count(distinct(uw.workflow_id, uw.user_name))`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you just want an aggregation query:

```
select uw.username, uw.team_id, t.teamname, count(*) as num_workflows
from user_workflows uw join
     tbl_teams t
     on uw.team_id = t.team_id
where uw.username = 'johndoe'
group by uw.username, uw.team_id, t.teamname;
```

Subqueries do not seem necessary for this or for your original query.

Comment: Unfortunately, user_workflows doesn't have **team_id**. It just has **user_name** and **workflow_id**